# Encode docx file to base64 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64

I'm downloading a docx file locally and want to encode this into base64, but it seems that encoding docx files does not work. I've tried this method with .txt and images and it does return a base64 string. Do I have to use a library or a different method to encode docx files?

```
async function encodeBase64(path) {
   let buff = fs.readFileSync(path);
   let base64data = buff.toString('base64');
   return base64data;
}

https.get(result['@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl'], function(response) {
        const file = encodeBase64(__dirname + "/temp/template.docx");
})
```

This results into an empty string.

Edit:

```
const file = encodeBase64(__dirname + "/temp/template.docx");
file.then(function(result) {
     console.log(result)
     return res.send(result);  
}).catch(function(error) {
     console.log(error)
})
```

With images and .txt files, it successfully logs the result in the console. When I attempt this with a docx file, it returns an empty string. I am absolutely certain it's choosing the docx file and it is also filled with content.

Comment: How did you arrive to the conclusion that it's not supported? I mean, what error or unexpected behavior are you getting?

Comment: You can do this with: https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Apologies, perhaps I should use a different word for it.

Comment: @Stuart Why? To open a file and convert its content to base64? Really?

Comment: Yes - you _can_ acheieve wit the MS office js lib...

Comment: @Stuart You can achieve that also by sending it to an external service that will do that for you. That doesn't make it a good idea.

Comment: There was no mention of any of this being a good idea... - unsure what point you are attempting to make mate? MS provide a js lib that provides functionality, OP doesnt have to use it...

Comment: I'm trying to make the point that suggesting adding a dependency to achieve something that can be easily done with the standard library is not a good suggestion. But, hey, it's not my codebase :)

Comment: @Stuart Although I do agree with Federico that adding a library for a singular functionality is exessive, but in this specific situation, I happen to be using Office.js, although I don't see where in the documentation this functionality is. With this library, I am trying to insert a docx file with a base64 string. That's why I am trying to convert a docx file to base64 first.

Comment: There are methods, such as: `SF.OUtil.encodeBase64`...

Comment: @Stuart I am using Office.js for the front-end, while I am trying to convert to base64 in the back-end. I'd prefer avoid using an entire library purely for one functionality. Also I can't seem to find anything about encoding to base64 in the Office.js documentation.

Answer (score 0):

What i have find out is you are not using async-await properly.

On this line:

```
const file = encodeBase64(__dirname + "/temp/template.docx");
```

ecvodeBase64() is async function and return a promise. What promise return goes either into `.then()` callback function or need to use await to retrieve the value.

To correct the above case you must do this:

```
https.get(result['@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl'], function(response) {
    encodeBase64(__dirname + "/temp/template.docx")
    .then( file => {
        // use file here
    });
});
```

or

```
https.get(result['@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl'], async function(response) {
    const file = await encodeBase64(__dirname + "/temp/template.docx");
})
```

Comment: Apologies, I haven't added the rest of my code. I indeed have a .then function after I call the function (NodeJS wouldn't compile the app otherwise). I have edited my code. I've also used 'await', but it doesn't work either.

I'm thinking either converting a docx file is too big or it simply doesn't work on docx files and only on txt/images and such.

Comment: You might need to use Buffer and some encoding check Buffer class in nodejs.